# how to user observer in angular

Tags: angular, http, get

Right now I am using subscribe for my Http GET request

#### Question:

how can I use Observable which will display the data without refreshing the page?

This is my Http GET method call:

```
 this.http.get(this.tenant_userlist).subscribe(response =>{
  this.users = response;
  this.dataSource.data = this.users;
});
```

I am using angular material table:

HTML:

```
          <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="user_id">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> User UID </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="User UID"> {{row.user_id}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> First Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="First Name" class="tab-data"> {{row.first_name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Last Name"> {{row.last_name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container

            <ng-container matColumnDef="email_id">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> Email ID </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Email ID"> {{row.email_id}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  > Action </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Action"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm shadow btnTable" >Edit</button>
              </mat-cell>  
            </ng-container>
            
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
            
          </mat-table>
```

Comment: I added in the HTMl file but I am getting error like this: "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Answer (score 1):

You can display a couple ways.

The Angular Twitter community has taken a liking to a template driven approach. Similar to @StyrianDev answer, but you won't need to subscribe to the http request in the component.

```
// component.ts

ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.http.get(this.tenant_userlist);
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
// component.html

<div *ngFor='let user of users | async'>
    {{user.name}}
</div>

// mat-table
<mat-table [dataSource]="users | async" matSort>
```

Or you can take a component driven approach, similar to what you are doing above.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.tenant_userlist).subscribe(response =>{
        this.users = response;
        this.dataSource = this.users;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor='let user of users'>
    {{user.name}}
</div>

// mat-table
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```

Note: If you want to use the [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your template, you'll need to import the CommonModule.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the async pipe as @StyrianDev mentioned, but in your case it should look like this:

```
<div *ngIf="users | async as users">
         <mat-table [dataSource]="users" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="user_id">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> User UID </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="User UID"> {{row.user_id}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="first_name">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> First Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="First Name" class="tab-data"> {{row.first_name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="last_name">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Last Name"> {{row.last_name}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container

            <ng-container matColumnDef="email_id">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-header-cell mat-sort-header> Email ID </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Email ID"> {{row.email_id}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  > Action </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" data-label="Action"> 
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm shadow btnTable" >Edit</button>
              </mat-cell>  
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

          </mat-table>
    </div>
```

This means that `users` should be an observable. In your ts file for this component, you should have your `users` property declared and you should set the value in the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook to return the observable from the HttpClient.Get method.

```
users: Observable<User[]>;

ngOnInit() {
   this.users = this.http.get(this.tenant_userlist);
}
```

Comment: I added in the HTMl file but I am getting error like this:   "InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'"

Comment: @RamKumar I updated my answer. You got the invalid pipe argument because the users object wasn't an observable. My edit should help

Answer (score 0):

To display this.users async just use the following syntax:

```
<div *ngFor='let user of users | async'>
    {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated my html table where should I add the async